# How to show a decreasing sequence is convergent and how to find its limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I just started studying real analysis and am having some trouble with this question:

**Show that the sequence given by x<sub>n+1</sub>=$\frac{1}{5-x_n}$, $x_0$=4 converges and find its limit.**

I can observe that the sequence is decreasing and bounded below and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x_{n+1}=0$.

Since $x_1 >x_2$ can I assume that $x_n > x_{n+1}$ then by induction $x_{n+1} > x_{n+2}$ so therefore the sequence is monotone decreasing. Would this be correct?

Knowing the limit is $0$ and $x_1\ge 0$ and $x_0\ge 0$ can I assume that $x_n\ge 0$, so then $\frac{1}{5-x_n}\ge0$, so $x_{n+1}\ge0$. Hence the sequence is bounded below by 0?
Therefore by the monotone convergence theorem the series converges.

Is any of this correct or on the right track, I feel like I'm missing something or more explaining in some of the induction bits, I'm not entirely sure if I'm using things correctly.

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: $x_n\ge 0$ does not imply that  $\frac{1}{5-x_n}\ge0$

Comment: Use induction to show that $0 \le x_n \le 4$ for all $n$.

Comment: $f((-\infty,4)) \subset (0,1]$, $f([0,1]) \subset [0,1]$ and $f'(x) \in [0,{1 \over 4^2})$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: $\lim_{n→∞}x_{+1}=0$ is not correct. This is the limit you have to find.

Comment: @user then how would I go about finding it, I'm unsure how to start.

Comment: I have written an answer.

Comment: @geetha290krm how do I go about showing that xn≥0?

Comment: If $x_n \le 4$ then $x_{n+1}=\frac 1 {5-x_n} \ge 0$. Use induction to prove $x_n \ge 0$ and $x_n \le 4$ simultaneously. Do not separate these two.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_n$ be the statement $1 \le x_n \le 4$. Surely, $P(1)$ is true. Suppose $P_n$ is true. Consider $x_{n+1}=\frac  1{5-x_n}$. Since $5-x_n$ lies between $1$ and $4$ it follows that $x_{n+1}$ lies between $\frac  1 4$ and $1$. In particular, $x_{n+1}$ lies between $1$ and $4$.

We have proved $P_n$ for each $n$. Now we get $x_{n+1} \le x_n$ since $\frac 1 {5-x_n} \le\frac 1 {5-4}=1\le x_n$.

Thus, $(x_n)$ is monotonically deereasing and bounded below by $0$. Hence it is convergent. Finding the limit is easy: The limit $l$ must satisy the quaiton $\frac 1 {5-l} =l$ which gives $l^{2}-5l+1=0$. The roots are $\frac {5\pm \sqrt {21}} 2$. But $\frac {5+ \sqrt {21}} 2>4$ so  the limit has to be$\frac {5- \sqrt {21}} 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the limit $L$ exists. Then it has to satisfy the equation:
$$
L=\frac1{5-L}
$$
or
$$
L=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{21}}2:=L_\pm.\tag1
$$
Observe $0<L_-<x_0<L_+<5$.

Next we can prove:
$$
\forall \{x_n:\ L_-<x_n<L_+\}:\quad L_-<x_{n+1}<x_n.\tag2
$$
Indeed, provided $ L_-<x_n<L_+$ we have:
$$
(L_+-x_n)(x_n-L_-)>0\implies 5x_n-x_n^2-1>0\implies
x_n>\frac1{5-x_n}=x_{n+1}
$$
and
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac1{5-x_n}>\frac1{5-L_-}=\frac1{L_+}=L_-.
$$
In view of $(2)$ the series [converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ one obtains:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L_-.
$$

Comment: The downvoter is welcome to make suggestions for improving the answer.